# jQuery each addition on total

Tags: javascript, jquery

1: How can a get the subtotal value based on each item value
2: When all calculation (each) is done how can I  fire a function that will contain the subtotal value.

```
var subtotal = 0;

//Check each price
$.each(item, function() {

 var itemprice = $(this).val();
 var subtotal = subtotal + itemprice;

});

//When all items are added in the subtotal do something...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `item` is a collection of prices...

```
var subtotal = 0;

//Check each price
$.each(item, function() {
    subtotal = subtotal + this;
});

//When all items are added in the subtotal do something...
alert(subtotal);
```

Remove the `var` before the second `subtotal` otherwise you are declaring a local variable rather than accessing the global one.

If the above code is already part of a function, then there is no need to call another function to do something with the subtotal (unless that code will be reused).

Comment: Thank you, I was getting the NaN. It was because of the var before the subtotal.

Comment: @FlorescuAdrian Using [jsLint](http://jslint.com/) can help in avoiding these types of bugs. Also, when adding something to an already existing variable you can use `+=` so you don't have to repeat the variable name. So, in this answer you could change `subtotal = subtotal + this;` to `subtotal += this;`

Answer (score 1):

Add an array and push each subtotal to array and loop thru the array to retrieve each item's subtotal

```
var subtotal = 0;
var subarr = [];
//Check each price
$.each(item, function() {

 var itemprice = $(this).val();
 var subtotal = subtotal + itemprice;
 subarr.push(subtotal);
});


function getEachItemSubTot(){
  for(var i=0;i<subarr.length;i++){
   console.log(subarr[i]);//get each item subtotal
  }
}
```